# QGIS howto create raster from map canvas easily

Tags: qgis, raster

i have question ho to create raster from QGIS map canvas (what i seen in my qgis) easily. Now i have used print composer and after some luck i get whole dataset into map item, after that i throw lucky guess for dpi and i get something.

What i would like to do is : make map look pretty in qgis, select cell resolution and get what i see in georeferenced raster file (geotiff, png etc..) from whole dataset. is this possible or do i just use print composer wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new feature in QGIS 2.2 Print Composer to be released in late February:

http://changelog.linfiniti.com/qgis/version/21/
(# Feature: World file generation)

Comment: does this also fix problem that it is not intuitive to define generated raster cell size etc. ? Also do you have download link for windows , i dont seem to find it anywhere

Comment: You can install version 2.1, which is the development version that will become 2.2 with the OSGeo4W installer.  Select "Advanced Install" then in the Desktop section choose qgis-dev.

Comment: Almoust works as needed, i just dont get high resolution out of it. Map area / page size / dpi  are good guess , and when i get 20kx20k pixels it wont work (out of memory). *sight*, I just want make retangle in qgis "canvas" windows , set cell size to 0.5m and get x amount of rasters which i can load in qgis ( well, actually send them to our geoserver admin ).  Maybe FME manages fix their mapnikRenderer so i can get those pesky cyrillic characters to map. Or i still use this wrong way.

Comment: this is  closest i get to what i want.

Comment: I did : PrintComposer , added Map view , page size = 500mmx500mm, defined scale = 1000 and dpi =500. set world file generation. I enabled atlas and select export as image. Results looks good , but for some reason qgis renders some "tiles" twice (difference is few meters in world file) (i use latest qgis weekly (2.1.0-54 )

Comment: Atlas failed, for some reason it created coverages like this http://www.picpaste.com/YUszoKXm.png lots ans lots overlaying. i was expecting nice "chess board" layout. Bug or stupid user error ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for "**Save as Image...**" in the File menu. Select an image format and you get an image file and a word file (georeference). The resolution of the raster image will be the same as the canvas.

If you need high resolution raster and world file together, you can use the commandline parameters of QGIS e.g. --project, --snapshot, --width, --height, --extent

Comment: i dont get this work : C:\OSGeo4W64>qgis --noplugins --project C:\\TMP\\this.qgs --snapshot res3.png  --width 200 --height 200
I have tried 2.0 dufor , and "latest" Qgis Weeksly which is 2.1.54 i think.

Comment: this doesn't work on my setup , Qgis Weekly standalone , OsgeoW64bit (2.01 qgis). Only result i get is that qgis is waiting whole night , takes x amount (depending width and height) RAM.

Comment: In QGIS documentation (http://qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/getting_started.html?highlight=snapshot) the command line parameters are marked by Linux logo (supported on Linux). Some commandline parameters works on Windows too, for example --lang --project, but --help --snapshot don't work.

Answer (score 1):

In QGIS 3, you can: File  Import/Export  Export Map to Image...

[image]

And you will have options to choose the extent:
[image]